# How to access target system (32 bit Linux) which is connected to my PC via USB Cable?

Tags: linux, networking, usb-drive, gdbserver

I want to run gdbserver on the target board. But I am unable to connect the target system from my VM Box **(x86_64 bit)**. Can you please help me?

In the target board, I am connecting **gdbserver** by localhost:5039 and it's listening on that port.

How to access this port from my VM Linux box?

Comment: What is your "target board"?

Comment: @duskwuff, Target board is a 32 bit Linux system.

Comment: There are a lot of 32-bit Linux systems out there. What *specific* type of device are you talking about here? Is it a computer, a cell phone, a toaster oven, an embedded development board? What kind of processor does it have on it, how is it connected to your computer, and with what type of cable or adapter?

Comment: @duskwuff, it's an embedded development board, has Linux variant "tiny OSEK", connected to  computer via USB adapter.